# Comparing two files and updating second file using bash and awk and sorting the second file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have two files with two colums in each file that I want to compare the 1st column of both files. If the value of the 1st column in the first file does not exist in the second file, I then want to append to the second file the value in the 1st column of the first file, eg

firstFile.log

```
1457935407,998181
1457964225,998191
1457969802,997896
```

secondFile.log

```
1457966024,1
1457967635,1
1457969802,5
1457975246,2
```

After, secondFile.log should look like:

```
1457935407,null
1457964225,null
1457966024,1
1457967635,1
1457969802,5
1457975246,2
```

Note: Second file should be sorted by the first column after being updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` and `sort`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} {delete a[$1]; print} END{
         for (i in a) print i, "null"}' firstFile.log secondFile.log |
sort -t, -k1 > $$.temp && mv $$.temp secondFile.log

1457935407,null
1457964225,null
1457966024,1
1457967635,1
1457969802,5
1457975246,2
```

Comment: Using FS in print instead of assigning OFS is not best practice.

Comment: Yes agreed :) I guess I was just lazy (fixed now)

Comment: This spews the results to the console and not update the second file.

Comment: Use: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} {delete a[$1]; print} END{for (i in a) print i, "null"}' firstFile.log secondFile.log | sort -t, -k1 > $$.temp && mv $$.temp secondFile.log`

Comment: That works fine, could you update the main answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1):

using non awk tools...

```
$ sort -t, -uk1,1 file2 <(sed 's/,.*/,null/' file1)

1457935407,null
1457964225,null
1457966024,1
1457967635,1
1457969802,5
1457975246,2
```

Comment: Very concise and works on the console however, it does not update the second file (like the second answer below). I event tried having an interim tmp file but can't get it to work.

Comment: it doesn't update anything, produces an output from both input files, you're free to do anything after that, i.e  `sort -t ..  > tmp && mv tmp file2` will replace file2 with the output of the script.

Comment: When I run this `sort -t, -uk1,1 file2 <(sed 's/,.*/,null/' file1) > file3` on the command line, it works and I get the file, when I run it inside a script, I get an error **Syntax error: "(" unexpected**

Comment: that means there is some syntax issue in your script.  Does you shebang specify `bash`?  It's not the default.

Comment: Does not seem to make a difference whether I put `!#/bin/bash` or `!#/bin/env bash`, but it works when I run it on the commandline! shebang?

Comment: perhaps you should try the correct syntax she-bang `#!/bin/bash`, not bang-she

Comment: Perhaps, **!#/bin/bash: not found**, I had it correct the first time round, maybe mispelled it here.

Comment: You're not seeing it correctly, please check character by character.  It's `#!` number sign (she) then exclamation point (bang) not the other way around.

Comment: Here's how it is, copied from the script: **#!/bin/bash** (I also tried with **#!/bin/env bash**), and I still get that bracket error.

Comment: Or, you can try `bash your_script_name` from the commandline.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106278/discussion-between-karakfa-and-nepaluz).

Comment: sorry, chat is blocked.  But I'm curious, can you post your script verbatim?

Comment: I actually responded in chat to you. **bash _script_name** worked! Also, here's the script: `#!/bin/bash sort -t, -uk1,1 file2 <(sed 's/,.*/,null/' file1) > file4` on two lines.

Comment: glad.  perhaps you have a non-standard installation. You can check `which bash` and follow the path to find where it's installed on your system.